# Flask - authenticate hashed password from SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

when I use basic authenticate of user login with name and plaintext password, user is logged in correctly.

Password is correctly hashed during registration.
When I store hashed password and try to authenticate it, program gives error:

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'`

Could you please tell me, what is wrong? I suspect that checking function can't find hashed password from SQLAlchemy database. Thank you.

When I use :

```
query = s.query(User).filter(User.username.in_([POST_USERNAME]))
```

I get:

`AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.password has an attribute 'split'`

```
   engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db', echo=True)

   app = Flask(__name__)
   app.config.from_object(__name__)
   app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'XXXXX'

   def hash_password(password):
        salt = uuid.uuid4().hex
        return hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + password.encode()).hexdigest() + ':' + salt

    def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
        password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
        return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

   Base = declarative_base()
   class User(Base):

       __tablename__ = "users"

       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       username = Column(String(64))
       password = Column(String(120))
       email = Column(String(64))

       def __init__(self, username, password, email):
           self.username = username
           self.password = password
           self.email = email

       def check_password(hashed_password, user_password):
           password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
           return password == hashlib.sha256(salt.encode() + user_password.encode()).hexdigest()

    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    @app.route("/")
     def index():
         return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
     def do_admin_login():
       POST_USERNAME = str(request.form['username'])
       POST_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password'])

       Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
       s = Session()
       user = User.query.filter_by(username=POST_USERNAME).first()
       if check_password(User.password, POST_PASSWORD) == True:
            session['logged_in'] = True
       else:
           flash('wrong password!')
       return index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query like this. `s` is your session.

`user = s.query(User).filter_by(username=POST_USERNAME).first()`

Then your if statement for check password is wrong. You're trying to use the model class instead of the user instance you just got. Should be:

`if check_password(user.password, POST_PASSWORD) == True:`

also some other pointers:  The module `Flask-SQLAlchemy` helps you use SQLAlchemy in Flask (defines your session globally).  Also consider using `bcrypt` for passwords. It is MUCH safer than SHA.

Comment: Working, thank you so much, I spend hours trying to solve it.  I will look in bcrypt, this is just for prototype and bcrypt was giving the same error, so it should be good now.